# Resizing view from cvShowImage

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I don't want to resize the entire image structure, but the images I am working with are too large to easily view with cvShowImage.  Is there a way to resize their view within the window created by cvShowImage?

Comment: Create new small image and call `cvResize` with original image as input and small image as output, then show small image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, you will have to create a new image structure and use cvResize.